# MATLAB surface from rotated closed curves

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

Essentially I am trying to create a volume by rotating a closed curve. I have attempted to use cylinder to achieve this, but I am getting undesirable results. I also have tried directly using surf. Here are those two attempts (newEl defined below).

```
elPatternPlot = plot3(newEl(:,1),newEl(:,2),newEl(:,3),'gr-','LineWidth',0.5);
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z')
grid on
```

Next, I rotate the 2D closed curve to the correct angle.

```
rotate(elPatternPlot, [1 0 0], 90);
```

To generate data points in the desired volume, I use rotate:

```
% Now rotate around z and store in the data
axObjs = azElFig.Children;
dataObjs = axObjs.Children;
xElData = dataObjs(1).XData;
yElData = dataObjs(1).YData;
zElData = dataObjs(1).ZData;

for a1=1:5:180
    rotate(elPatternPlot, [0 0 1], a1);
    axObjs = azElFig.Children;
    dataObjs = axObjs.Children;   

    xElData = [xElData dataObjs(1).XData];
    yElData = [yElData dataObjs(1).YData];
    zElData = [zElData dataObjs(1).ZData]; 
end
plot3(xElData,yElData,zElData,'r-','LineWidth',0.5)
```

And the result:
[image]

This this yields the correct outside geometry, but I am seeking to create a volume. From here I use surf:

```
xv = linspace(min(xElData), max(xElData), 150);
yv = linspace(min(yElData), max(yElData), 150);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(xv, yv);            
Z = griddata(xElData,yElData,zElData,X,Y);

figure; surf(X,Y,Z);
```

The output is:
[image]

Using cylinder,

```
[x,y,z] = cylinder(Z);
figure; surf(x,y,z)
```

I obtain:
[image]

The desired surface should look more like (from the bottom):
[image]

And from the side, a filled in version of this:
[image]

```
newEl =
 -906.5000  -36.5000         0
 -909.5000  -65.5000         0
 -903.5000  -91.5000         0
 -891.5000 -139.5000         0
 -877.5000 -203.5000         0
 -863.5000 -238.5000         0
 -855.5000 -254.5000         0
 -847.5000 -269.5000         0
 -839.5000 -284.5000         0
 -784.5000 -369.5000         0
 -771.5000 -384.5000         0
 -746.5000 -406.5000         0
 -733.5000 -421.5000         0
 -695.5000 -457.5000         0
 -668.5000 -479.5000         0
 -641.5000 -496.5000         0
 -614.5000 -513.5000         0
 -600.5000 -525.5000         0
 -573.5000 -544.5000         0
 -561.5000 -549.5000         0
 -549.5000 -553.5000         0
 -488.5000 -579.5000         0
 -474.5000 -585.5000         0
 -460.5000 -592.5000         0
 -446.5000 -599.5000         0
 -417.5000 -603.5000         0
 -388.5000 -607.5000         0
 -293.5000 -611.5000         0
 -277.5000 -608.5000         0
 -246.5000 -597.5000         0
 -231.5000 -593.5000         0
 -187.5000 -578.5000         0
 -160.5000 -553.5000         0
 -133.5000 -528.5000         0
 -120.5000 -512.5000         0
  -85.5000 -478.5000         0
  -61.5000 -428.5000         0
  -56.5000 -411.5000         0
  -47.5000 -359.5000         0
  -42.5000 -342.5000         0
  -33.5000 -289.5000         0
  -28.5000 -271.5000         0
  -19.5000 -220.5000         0
  -14.5000 -202.5000         0
   -5.5000 -149.5000         0
   -0.5000 -132.5000         0
    4.5000 -128.5000         0
    9.5000 -161.5000         0
   18.5000 -194.5000         0
   23.5000 -226.5000         0
   32.5000 -261.5000         0
   37.5000 -293.5000         0
   42.5000 -324.5000         0
   51.5000 -359.5000         0
   56.5000 -390.5000         0
   65.5000 -426.5000         0
   70.5000 -455.5000         0
  125.5000 -517.5000         0
  138.5000 -528.5000         0
  165.5000 -556.5000         0
  178.5000 -567.5000         0
  192.5000 -578.5000         0
  207.5000 -585.5000         0
  251.5000 -596.5000         0
  267.5000 -604.5000         0
  298.5000 -611.5000         0
  393.5000 -607.5000         0
  422.5000 -602.5000         0
  451.5000 -597.5000         0
  465.5000 -592.5000         0
  479.5000 -586.5000         0
  493.5000 -580.5000         0
  530.5000 -565.5000         0
  542.5000 -559.5000         0
  554.5000 -552.5000         0
  592.5000 -534.5000         0
  619.5000 -515.5000         0
  646.5000 -496.5000         0
  673.5000 -477.5000         0
  725.5000 -430.5000         0
  738.5000 -419.5000         0
  776.5000 -379.5000         0
  789.5000 -368.5000         0
  801.5000 -353.5000         0
  811.5000 -336.5000         0
  836.5000 -292.5000         0
  844.5000 -279.5000         0
  852.5000 -268.5000         0
  860.5000 -253.5000         0
  881.5000 -200.5000         0
  886.5000 -184.5000         0
  891.5000 -167.5000         0
  895.5000 -146.5000         0
  902.5000 -104.5000         0
  907.5000  -90.5000         0
  909.5000  -46.5000         0
  904.5000    6.5000         0
  899.5000   58.5000         0
  897.5000   60.5000         0
  875.5000  126.5000         0
  867.5000  142.5000         0
  828.5000  208.5000         0
  820.5000  224.5000         0
  763.5000  276.5000         0
  750.5000  289.5000         0
  712.5000  319.5000         0
  699.5000  332.5000         0
  686.5000  341.5000         0
  659.5000  360.5000         0
  632.5000  378.5000         0
  605.5000  396.5000         0
  578.5000  416.5000         0
  566.5000  431.5000         0
  517.5000  496.5000         0
  505.5000  509.5000         0
  436.5000  567.5000         0
  407.5000  587.5000         0
  377.5000  603.5000         0
  361.5000  604.5000         0
  345.5000  606.5000         0
  329.5000  607.5000         0
  313.5000  608.5000         0
  282.5000  610.5000         0
  236.5000  606.5000         0
  221.5000  601.5000         0
  151.5000  567.5000         0
  111.5000  547.5000         0
  100.5000  533.5000         0
   89.5000  520.5000         0
   79.5000  500.5000         0
   60.5000  477.5000         0
   46.5000  454.5000         0
   27.5000  427.5000         0
   13.5000  403.5000         0
  -10.5000  403.5000         0
  -24.5000  423.5000         0
  -38.5000  444.5000         0
  -52.5000  465.5000         0
  -66.5000  486.5000         0
  -75.5000  502.5000         0
  -96.5000  531.5000         0
 -107.5000  548.5000         0
 -147.5000  566.5000         0
 -174.5000  581.5000         0
 -202.5000  591.5000         0
 -217.5000  600.5000         0
 -262.5000  611.5000         0
 -309.5000  607.5000         0
 -325.5000  607.5000         0
 -341.5000  606.5000         0
 -357.5000  604.5000         0
 -373.5000  603.5000         0
 -403.5000  587.5000         0
 -432.5000  566.5000         0
 -501.5000  511.5000         0
 -513.5000  494.5000         0
 -525.5000  478.5000         0
 -537.5000  463.5000         0
 -587.5000  407.5000         0
 -628.5000  380.5000         0
 -655.5000  361.5000         0
 -682.5000  341.5000         0
 -708.5000  320.5000         0
 -721.5000  311.5000         0
 -759.5000  277.5000         0
 -797.5000  244.5000         0
 -807.5000  237.5000         0
 -816.5000  224.5000         0
 -824.5000  213.5000         0
 -832.5000  199.5000         0
 -871.5000  124.5000         0
 -882.5000  104.5000         0
 -887.5000   98.5000         0
 -894.5000   72.5000         0
 -896.5000   37.5000         0
 -899.5000   34.5000         0
 -901.5000    1.5000         0
 -906.5000  -36.5000         0
```

Comment: I'm gonna put this as a comment because it doesn't fully answer the question. You can find the convex hull of your data using ````convhull```` and then plot it with ````trimesh```` or ````trisurf````.
`K=convhull(xElData,yElData,zElData);`
 `figure; trisurf(K,xElData,yElData,zElData);`
This doesn't fully answer the question because it will enclose the top and bottom of the figure--your curve isn't perfectly convex. Just leaving this as a tip for anyone who wanted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost had it right. The problem is within how you rotate inside the for loop.

Your code:

```
for a1=1:5:180
    rotate(elPatternPlot, [0 0 1], a1);
    ...
end
```

`a1` is incremented by 5 as it iterates. Therefore, you are not rotating it by a step of 5.

To fix this, simply change

```
rotate(elPatternPlot, [0 0 1], a1);
```

to

```
rotate(elPatternPlot, [0 0 1], 5);
```

To make it easier to plot your figures, you can keep your data in matrix form:

```
for a1=1:5:180
    rotate(elPatternPlot, [0 0 1], 5);

    xElData = [xElData; elPatternPlot.XData];
    yElData = [yElData; elPatternPlot.YData];
    zElData = [zElData; elPatternPlot.ZData]; 
end
```

To plot:

```
figure
plot3(xElData, yElData, zElData)
grid on; axis equal

figure
surf(xElData, yElData, zElData)
grid on; axis equal

figure
mesh(xElData, yElData, zElData)
grid on; axis equal
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Excellent. I was hoping I was not too far off. I could not replicate what you did at first, until I noticed your comment on putting the data into matrix form.